# Facebook oopen graph doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I have a website: www.frejno.com.pl .
I added og:image in a head but the FB debugger return that the image is too small or FB can't get it. What should I do? This is wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

What does your og:image tag look like? It should work if you follow the example in the [Facebook Open Graph Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/object/) and use something like:

```
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://domain.com/path-to-your-image.png" />
```

Comment: O gave you a site. You can see there a og:image content

Comment: I used Facebook's [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) to 'fetch new scrape information' for your site. Looks like it's pulling an image with the link now.